# Copy and cast a float matrix into a double matrix using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, void-pointers

I have a pointer to a double  matrix dmatrix which I declared using:

```
double* dmatrix = malloc(n*n*sizeof(double));
```

I also have a void pointer to a matrix imatrix, which has int values for a matrix of the same dimensions.
The int matrix is filled elsewhere in the program. How can I copy the values from imatric to dmatrix using just pointers?
This is what I an trying.:

```
void *a;      
for(int c=0;c<n;c++){
  for(int r=0;r<n;r++){
    a = ((char *)imatrix+(r*n+c)*sizeof(int));
    *(dmatrix+r*n+c) = *(double *)a;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is the `imatrix` a void pointer? If you assign it to an int-pointer you can just index it normally: `int * iimatrix = imatrix; /* for loops */ dmatrix[r*n + c] = iimatrix[r*n + c];`

Comment: What happens when you try it?  Does it work as expected?   Can you show an example of expected and actual output?

Comment: You have to cast the *values*, not the *pointers*.  I'm note sure from your code what you're actually trying to do.  Also, your title says `float` and `double` but your text says `double` and `int`.

Comment: Ill add the expected vs actual results now. And the imatrix is a void pointer, because thats the specification. If I had my way, I would do what you suggested

Answer (score 4):

Wrong.
1. You say imatrix points to int matrix, while you convert it to char*. Why?
2. a is supposedly a pointer in the source matrix. Why do you cast it to (double *)?

I would do something like that:

```
void* imatrix;
double* dmatrix;

double* p_dmatrix = dmatrix;
int* p_imatrix = imatrix;

for(int i=0; i< r*c; i++)
    *p_dmatrix++ = *p_imatrix++;
```

Comment: No need to cast `imatrix`: conversions to and from `void` pointers are done automatically.

Comment: The `p_` variables are redundant, the loop could be `dmatrix[i] = imatrix[i];`

Comment: While the loop vould be rewritten without p_ variables, indexing operation involves multiplication and addition, which take more time then incrementing a pointer. Absent optimization  information, I stand for the existing solution